# See all the questions that were marked as duplicate of my questions

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I am curious to see a list with the *question that were marked as duplicate of **my questions***.

Maybe a [SQL script](https://data.stackexchange.com/)? Other ways?

Example:

> Questions posted by me: `A`, `B`
>
> Question posted by others: `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`
>
> `C` is duplicate of `A`. `D` and `E` are duplicates of `B`
>
> The script should return `C`, `D`, `E`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following data explorer query shows all posts that were marked as duplicates of questions you asked:

```sql
SELECT pl.PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM PostLinks pl
JOIN Posts q ON pl.RelatedPostId = q.Id
WHERE
pl.LinkTypeId = 3
AND q.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
```

I've put an updated version of this query on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173779/all-questions-marked-as-duplicates-of-your-own-questions?UserId=1420197), producing a sorted listing of duplicates and your questions that they were closed as duplicates of.

Comment: I would love to have this feature, not just for my question, but for any questions. This could be very useful if one want to look up for more insights.