# What is the meaning of postlinks table?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I have looked into 
[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

But there is no explanation about the `postlinks` table. Can anyone explain me the meaning of each column of that table?

Comment: There are Id, CreationDate, PostId, RelatedPostID and LinkTypeId fields

Comment: Look at the *Linked* section to the right of your question. I believe your answer lies there.

Comment: If a post has duplicates (or has linked posts), this table holds that data.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The FAQ doesn't actually document that table..

Comment: @Martijn, I was actually referring to the section itself, not to the content of the FAQ link there :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ah, yes, but that doesn't actually explain the contents of the schema, not as such. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The table lists all 'linked' and 'duplicate' links related to a post.

You can use it to [query what posts are linked as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224716/140890) for example.

Schema explanation:

### PostLinks

- `Id` - primary key
- `CreationDate` - when the link was created
- `PostId` - id of source post
- `RelatedPostId` - id of target post
- `LinkTypeId` - type of link (currently either 1, linked, or 3, dupe)

Linked post are any internal link referenced in the question or in answers or comments below a question. Duplicate links are created when the source post has been closed as a duplicate.

Quoting from the [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/140890), the `LinkTypeId` values are:

> - 1 = Linked (`PostId` contains a link to `RelatedPostId`)
> - 3 = Duplicate (`PostId` is a duplicate of `RelatedPostId`)

The `PostId` column only ever refers to *questions*; the vast majority of `RelatedPostId` targets are questions too, with about 1000 exceptions (which are answers); it is unclear when the site will insert an answer link instead of a question, but all these exceptions are 'linked' links, not duplicates.

Comment: For a question does this include links that are in answers?

Comment: @IanRingrose: scratch that, I was wrong. Yes, links in answers *are* linked from the question id.

Comment: @IanRingrose: I posted a 'see this other answer of mine' reference in a post that I used to test this with; neither the source answer ID nor the target answer are listed in the PostLinks table, but the questions *are*. So answerA posted on questionA refers to answerB on questionB, and a link was addded from questionA to questionB.

Comment: There is no `PostLinkTypes` table on SEDE.

Comment: @ashleedawg: that table appears to have been removed. It [was there when this answer was written](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2678/31).