# Why are there values of 1 and 3 for LinkTypeId and no value of 2? (Stack Exchange data dump)

Tags: support, data-dump, schema

I have found an explanation for LinkTypeId 1 and 3 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226837/what-is-the-meaning-of-postlinks-table). Why was the second type skipped?

Comment: It might not have been skipped, the value simply isn't made available in the public. I don't have access to the code base so I can only speculate. Maybe LinkTypeId =2 holds the Related information (see what is in the sidebar of the question: Linked  is represented with LinkTypeId =1, Related might be represented with LinkTypeId = 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data-dump and the Stack Exchange Data Explorer schema are limited selections of the actual production database schema. But when tables and/or data is made available the production schema is followed with filters/views applied to remove the data that should stay private, for various reasons.

In the production database LinkTypeId = 2 does occur. I already speculated on that but [Twitter never forgets](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1280500388228214785/photo/1).

In that screenshot and tweet from [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) we see him discuss improvements over this (paraphrased) [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1618678):

```sql
DECLARE @relatedMax tinyint = 10,
        @Questionid int = 309786;

Select Top(@relatedMax)
       p.Id,
       p.Title,
       p.Score,
       Cast(Case When p.AcceptedAnswerid is Null Then 0 else 0 End as bit) HasAcceptedAnswer,
       pl.Rank,
       pl.CreationDate
From PostLinks pl
     Join Posts p on pl.RelatedPostId = p.Id
Where pl.PostId = @QuestionId
  And pl.LinkTypeId = 2 -- {=Related}
  And p.DeletionDate is null;
```

In the Where clause we can confirm our gut feeling: LinkTypeId does take a value of 2 meaning "Related". As bonus we see further down a LinkTypeId with value 4 meaning "Collection"

So, to answer the question: The value 2 wasn't skipped. It is used in the production schema of the database. Unfortunately that value isn't made publicly available. You need the Stack API if you want those: [How to get related questions' IDs of a certain question in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293458/how-to-get-related-questions-ids-of-a-certain-question-in-stack-overflow)

---

<sub>[*image captured from Twitter in case that Tweet ever gets deleted*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jj7S.jpg)</sub>

Comment: This is irrelevant since there's no reason the values need to be consecutive or any particular values at all.